# Best way to execute post deploy script on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, pm2, heroku-api

To run my app on heroku I use [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/), and I configure my [Procfile](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/use-pm2-with-cloud-providers/) with:

```
worker: node main.js
```

Before start my app, I need to configure same modules of pm2 with script

```
npm i -g pm2

pm2 install pm2-logrotate
pm2 install pm2-slack

pm2 set pm2-slack:slack_url $SLACK_URL
pm2 set pm2-slack:log true
pm2 set pm2-slack:error true
pm2 set pm2-slack:restart true
pm2 set pm2-slack:exist true
pm2 set pm2-slack:start true
pm2 set pm2-slack:online true
pm2 set pm2-slack:stop true
```

So, where put this scripts?

### Tried

I try to put in `postinstall` script on `package.json`

```
  .... 
  "scripts": {
    "start": "pm2 start ecosystem.json",
    "postinstall": "sh post-install.sh"
  },
```

When I loggin into `heroku run bash`

```
λ heroku run bash
Running bash on <heroku-server>... up, run.XXX
~ $ pm2 l

                        -------------

   Looking for a complete monitoring and management tool for PM2?
    _                             _        _            _
   | | _____ _   _ _ __ ___   ___| |_ _ __(_) ___ ___  (_) ___
   | |/ / _ \ | | | '_ ` _ \ / _ \ __| '__| |/ __/ __| | |/ _ \
   |   <  __/ |_| | | | | | |  __/ |_| |  | | (__\__ \_| | (_) |
   |_|\_\___|\__, |_| |_| |_|\___|\__|_|  |_|\___|___(_)_|\___/
             |___/

                          Features

                   - Real Time Dashboard
                   - CPU/Memory monitoring
                   - HTTP monitoring
                   - Event notification
                   - Custom value monitoring
                   - Real Time log display

                          Checkout

                   https://keymetrics.io/

                        -------------

[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon
[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
┌──────────┬────┬──────┬─────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬────────┬──────────┐
│ App name │ id │ mode │ pid │ status │ restart │ uptime │ memory │ watching │
└──────────┴────┴──────┴─────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴────────┴──────────┘
 Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
```

### Questions

1. My Procfile was not executed? Why?
2. Where the best place to put mu postinstall script? Should I create my own buildpack and put here?

Comment: Which buildpack are you using currently? Also, did you see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#heroku-specific-build-steps ? I don't know too much about node, so sorry if this does not help.